# How to manage Proxy in Jmeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I have to do performance test of a web based application through Jmeter. To connect to the application , I have to be in Client VPN and it has specific proxy to connect. The application will NOT work in Local host..

How to perform this? I tried by running Jmeter from command prompt . Please help .

Comment: I tried by running Jmeter from command prompt by still no luck.. Is there anything to be done with Port

Answer (score 1):

You can configure JMeter to use proxy in 2 ways:

1. [Command-line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

   ```
   jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port
   ```
2. Using [*system.properties*](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (the file lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, add the next lines to it:

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
   https.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
   https.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

Answer (score 0):

First check that you have the correct proxy parameters like Proxy Server IP/address,port no,username and password.

Then, in the first HTTP Request, click on advanced tab and there you find Proxy server section.

[image]

Fill the required information and run the jmeter. Based on the response you can judge where you are able to send the request via proxy or not.

I have used it with proxy server name with username and pwd. For me it worked, by that I means you can try by whatever information you have.
Then, you can set the properties permanently as suggested by Dmitri. Also, it can be set in HTTP Request Default Config.

Check the below link for more information:-
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request